# Error in accessing SonarQube dashboard on localhost:9000

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I was configuring SonarQube 6.1 on my PC and initially i was able to view sonarqube dashboard on localhost:9000. But after doing required changes in configuration files(sonar and wrapper) ,after creating db in sql server i am NOT ABLE to see sonar dashboard on localhost:9000 ,its giving network error(tcp_error).
Sql server connection :
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=sonar;integratedSecurity=true.
Any hint will be appreciated.

i am attaching the logs here :

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2018.02.14 19:22:49 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\Sonarqube 6.1\temp
2018.02.14 19:22:49 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Sonarqube 6.1\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\Sonarqube 6.1\temp\sq-process2295132313122351201properties
2018.02.14 19:22:51 INFO   es[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting es
2018.02.14 19:22:51 INFO   es[][o.s.s.EsSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2018.02.14 19:22:51 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] version[2.3.3], pid[69296], build[218bdf1/2016-05-17T15:40:04Z]
2018.02.14 19:22:51 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] initializing ...
2018.02.14 19:22:51 INFO   es[][o.e.plugins]  [sonarqube] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2018.02.14 19:22:51 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonarqube] using [1] data paths, mounts [[C (C:)]], net usable_space [17.2gb], net total_space [97.6gb], spins? [unknown], types [NTFS]
2018.02.14 19:22:51 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonarqube] heap size [990.7mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2018.02.14 19:23:10 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] initialized
2018.02.14 19:23:10 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] starting ...
2018.02.14 19:23:10 INFO   es[][o.e.transport]  [sonarqube] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9001}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9001}
2018.02.14 19:23:10 INFO   es[][o.e.discovery]  [sonarqube] sonarqube/SiLqQ7h5TnqOmun2zWvO_w
2018.02.14 19:23:14 INFO   es[][o.e.cluster.service]  [sonarqube] new_master {sonarqube}{SiLqQ7h5TnqOmun2zWvO_w}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}{rack_id=sonarqube, master=true}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
2018.02.14 19:23:14 INFO   es[][o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonarqube] started
2018.02.14 19:23:15 INFO   es[][o.e.gateway]  [sonarqube] recovered [5] indices into cluster_state
2018.02.14 19:23:19 INFO   es[][o.e.c.r.allocation]  [sonarqube] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[tests][4]] ...]).
2018.02.14 19:23:19 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2018.02.14 19:23:19 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx1024m -Xms512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Sonarqube 6.1\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;C:\Sonarqube 6.1\lib\jdbc\mssql\sqljdbc42.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Sonarqube 6.1\temp\sq-process6566518313829106923properties
2018.02.14 19:23:20 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2018.02.14 19:23:21 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: C:\Sonarqube 6.1\web
2018.02.14 19:23:21 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2018.02.14 19:23:22 INFO  web[][o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2018.02.14 19:23:24 INFO  web[][o.e.plugins] [The Stepford Cuckoos] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2018.02.14 19:23:25 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9001]
2018.02.14 19:23:25 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 6.1 / dc148a71a1c184ccad588b66251980c994879dff
2018.02.14 19:23:25 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=sonar;integratedSecurity=true
2018.02.14 19:23:28 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerFileSystemImpl] SonarQube home: C:\Sonarqube 6.1
2018.02.14 19:23:28 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin C# / 5.3.1 / 829e9f5ce2582c2e45f2db2130d2fbaa509fbc64
2018.02.14 19:23:28 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Git / 1.2 / a713dd64daf8719ba4e7f551f9a1966c62690c17
2018.02.14 19:23:28 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Java / 4.0 / b653c6c8640ab3d6015d036a060f58e027a653af
2018.02.14 19:23:28 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin JavaScript / 2.14 / 8e37a262d72dd863345f9c6e87421e2d1853a2e6
2018.02.14 19:23:28 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SVN / 1.3 / aff503d48bc77b07c2b62abf93249d0a20bd355c
2018.02.14 19:23:30 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying Ruby on Rails applications
2018.02.14 19:23:31 INFO  web[][o.s.d.c.MssqlCharsetHandler] Verify that database collation is case-sensitive and accent-sensitive
2018.02.14 19:23:33 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: https://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2018.02.14 19:23:38 INFO  web[][o.s.s.n.NotificationDaemon] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2018.02.14 19:23:39 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
2018.02.14 19:23:41 INFO  web[][o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
2018.02.14 19:23:45 INFO  web[][o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register quality profiles
2018.02.14 19:23:47 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters] Register measure filters
2018.02.14 19:23:47 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterDashboards] Register dashboards
2018.02.14 19:23:47 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates] Register permission templates
2018.02.14 19:23:47 INFO  web[][o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys] Rename deprecated property keys
2018.02.14 19:23:47 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index issues
2018.02.14 19:23:47 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index tests
2018.02.14 19:23:47 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index users
2018.02.14 19:23:47 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index views
2018.02.14 19:23:48 INFO  web[][jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_152-b16 [Windows 10-amd64]
2018.02.14 19:23:48 INFO  web[][jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2018.02.14 19:25:23 INFO  web[][jruby.rack] keeping custom (config.logger) Rails logger instance
2018.02.14 19:25:24 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter@4dbb34d2 [pattern=org.sonar.api.web.ServletFilter$UrlPattern@d28af38]
2018.02.14 19:25:24 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.InitFilter@65316401 [pattern=org.sonar.api.web.ServletFilter$UrlPattern@7138d1d1]
2018.02.14 19:25:24 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter@70eb9145 [pattern=org.sonar.api.web.ServletFilter$UrlPattern@1e14f235]
2018.02.14 19:25:24 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.LoginAction@33c29508 [pattern=org.sonar.api.web.ServletFilter$UrlPattern@afe5c1f]
2018.02.14 19:25:24 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.w.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.ValidateAction@6e03c549 [pattern=org.sonar.api.web.ServletFilter$UrlPattern@49ce7754]
2018.02.14 19:25:24 INFO  web[][o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2018.02.14 19:25:24 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2018.02.14 19:25:24 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2018.02.14 19:25:24 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
2018.02.14 19:25:24 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[ce]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Sonarqube 6.1\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;./lib/ce/*;C:\Sonarqube 6.1\lib\jdbc\mssql\sqljdbc42.jar org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer C:\Sonarqube 6.1\temp\sq-process3506711799158227159properties
2018.02.14 19:25:27 INFO  ce[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting ce
2018.02.14 19:25:27 INFO  ce[][o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine starting up...
2018.02.14 19:25:29 INFO  ce[][o.e.plugins] [Gorgon] modules [], plugins [], sites []
2018.02.14 19:25:31 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9001]
2018.02.14 19:25:32 INFO  ce[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=sonar;integratedSecurity=true
2018.02.14 19:25:34 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.p.ServerFileSystemImpl] SonarQube home: C:\Sonarqube 6.1
2018.02.14 19:25:34 INFO  ce[][o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Load plugins
2018.02.14 19:25:40 INFO  ce[][o.s.s.c.q.PurgeCeActivities] Delete the Compute Engine tasks created before Fri Aug 18 19:25:40 IST 2017
2018.02.14 19:25:40 INFO  ce[][o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine is up
2018.02.14 19:25:40 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[ce] is up
```

Comment: SonarQube 6.1.... Why?

Comment: The log looks ok. Did you change the default port-number 9000 in the SonarQube configuration file?

Comment: hi Ann, why as in..? should i be using some other version ?

Comment: HI Jeroen , no i haven't changed default port its sonar.web.port=9000 .

Comment: In order to get the best support you should use a LTS version. Did you follow the [docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server), including the JDBC Driver package?